# How to conditionally render a data attribute based on props in react

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am scratching my head with this one (should be so easy) but I'm struggling to work out how to conditionally render a data attribute based on props being passed down.

Here is the code snippet WITHOUT the extra data attribute but showing a working ternary operator

```
<ul
 data-slider
 ref={carouselEL}
 className={props.trending ? "flex lg:grid lg:grid-3" : "flex transition lg:w-full"}
>
```

Here is an example with the additional data attribute, yet the bottom line of code throws an error and doesn't work.

```
<ul
 data-slider
 ref={carouselEL}
 className={props.trending ? "flex lg:grid lg:grid-3" : "flex transition lg:w-full"}
 {props.trending && dataTrending}
>
```

Any ideas?

To confirm the desired output for a carousel WITH data trending true should be

```
<ul
 data-slider
 class="flex lg:grid lg:grid-3"
 data-trending
>
```

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Soorry but I don't understand the question, ¿you want to conditionally give a vaue to `data-slider`?

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: What is the desired output where you have `{props.trending && dataTrending}`?

Comment: What is the optional attribute name and what would be it's value?

Comment: Please see updated question :)

Comment: I think this may help: `<button
        data-prop={true ? 22 : undefined}` if it was false and you'll do `document.querySelectorAll('button')[0].getAttribute('data-prop')` then you'll get `null` since React didn't set the data-prop on that element.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick if you want just the data attribute without any value:

```
<ul data-trending={props.trending ? '' : null} >
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the unordered list (`<ul>` element) You have to generate list item (`<li>` element) for each entry, like so:

```
<ul
 data-slider
 ref={carouselEL}
 className={props.trending ? "flex lg:grid lg:grid-3" : "flex transition lg:w-full"}
>
  {props.trending ? dataTrending.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li> : null}
</ul>
```

#### A few notes

- In order to "help" react to better render and update the `<ul>` element we're passing the `key` prop
- In the function `Array.prototype.map` the first argument is the item and the second one is the item index in the array, read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: OP asks about conditionally generate component's properties and not how to generate children.

Answer (score 0):

In [`JSX`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-in-jsx), properties must be `key-value` pairs,
that's why such code is a `SyntaxError`:

```
<ul
 {props.trending && dataTrending}
/>

----

SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "..." (2:3)
  1 | <ul
> 2 |  {props.trending && dataTrending}
    |   ^
  3 | />
```

Here are some use cases to handle component properties:

```
const divStyle = {
  style: { width: 200, padding: 5, border: '1px solid black' }
};

const conditionalProps = isTrue ? divStyle : null;

<>
  <div {...divStyle}>Toggle Props</div>

  <div style={value ? { ...divStyle.style } : null}>Toggle Props</div>

  <div {...conditionalProps}>Toggle Props</div>
</>
```

[image: Edit Q-58302482-AttributesJSX]

In your case:

```
<ul
 dataSlider
 ref={carouselEL}
 className={props.trending ? "flex lg:grid lg:grid-3" : "flex transition lg:w-full"}
 dataTrending={props.trending ? {...dataTrending} : null}

 // May cause a bug due to short circuit.
 // dataTrending={props.trending && dataTrending}
/>

// Or
const dataTrendingProp = props.trending ? dataTrending : null;
<ul
 dataSlider
 ref={carouselEL}
 className={props.trending ? "flex lg:grid lg:grid-3" : "flex transition lg:w-full"}
  {...dataTrendingProp}
/>
```

> **Note:** In JSX, attributes [should be `camelCased`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html), i.e `dataSlider` ant not `data-slider`
>
> "In React, all DOM properties and attributes (including event handlers) should be camelCased. For example, the HTML attribute tabindex corresponds to the attribute tabIndex in React."